# Match prompt with unicode

Tags: javascript

I am trying to write a script that prompts for a string and alerts whether or not the entered string contains either a backslash or a Telugu letter "ddha" (U+0C22).

This is my code:

```
string = prompt("Enter a string")
emoji = fixFromCharCode(U+0C22); 

if (string === "/") {
    alert("There is a / in the string");
} else (string === emoji) {
    alert("There is a " + emoji + " in the string")
}
```

I am receiving an "Unexpected token ILLEGAL" error. How would I be able to match the prompt with the Unicode?

Comment: @StephenC This is javascript. I requested removal of the java tag, because that's just confusing.

Comment: It seems tagging `java` is not required.

Answer (score 1):

replace `emoji = fixFromCharCode(U+0C22);` with `emoji = fixFromCharCode("\u0c22");`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
string = prompt("Enter a string")
emoji = String.fromCharCode(3106);  // decimal value of 0C22 

if (string === "/") {
    alert("There is a / in the string");
} else if(string === emoji) {
    alert("There is a " + emoji + " in the string")
}
```

Note: Edited to change the character code to its decimal representation.

Also note that your text described looking for a backslash, but your code checks for a forward slash.

And also... your code, which appears in fixed up form above, checks for a single-character string that is exactly equal to "/" or "emoji".  Your problem statement says, "contains."  So, if you want to detect something like, "There is a / in this string" some more work is needed.  I think this will do it:

```
string = prompt("Enter a string")
emoji = String.fromCharCode(3106);  // decimal value of 0C22 

if (string.indexOf("/") > -1) {     // Checks for "contains" instead of equals
    alert("There is a / in the string");
} else if (string.indexOf(emoji) > -1) {
    alert("There is a " + emoji + " in the string")
}
```